# Django: Identify the urls that provide duplicate content and set a canonical link

Tags: django, url, seo, django-views

models.py

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    meters_away = models.IntegerField()
```

Lets populate the db:

```
>>> from people.models import People
>>> a = People()
>>> a.name = 'George'
>>> a.meters_away = 15
>>> a.save()
>>> b = People()
>>> b.name = 'Jim'
>>> b.meters_away = 10
>>> b.save()
```

Supposing that we have a url that returns all people in a range of x meters:

`http://example.com/range/<meters>`

This url scheme accepts 3 hits as follows:

1. `http://example.com/range/20`
2. `http://example.com/range/30`
3. `http://example.com/range/40`

Those hits will create the following queries:

```
>>> hit1 = People.objects.filter(meters_away__lt=20)
>>> hit2 = People.objects.filter(meters_away__lt=30)
>>> hit3 = People.objects.filter(meters_away__lt=40)
```

Where:

```
>>> list(hit1) == list(hit2) == list(hit3)
>>> True
```

This means that `example.com`, will serve 3 different urls with the same content.

From a SEO point of view, how could all the possible urls (meters: 21, 22, 23, 24, 30, 40 etc) be filtered in a way that a canonical url is appended to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i understood your question, you may want to get the maximum distance in meters that produce the same result as the current distance (say `m` meters):

```
next_number = People.objects.filter(meters_away__gte=m).order_by('meters_away')[:1]
next_number = next_number[0] if next_number else m
```

and the canonical url will be:

`http://example.com/range/<next_number>`

Comment: My example is trivial and lacks crucial factors that might make it more robust. Nonetheless, your answer reveals the idea that will make it work. Thank you!